# Binned histogram of timings in log file on command line

Tags: linux, command-line, histogram, binning

To quickly evaluate the timings of various operations from a log file on a linux server, I would like to extract them from the log and create a textual/tsv style histogram. To have a better idea of how the timings are distributed, I want to bin them into ranges of 0-10ms, 10-20ms etc.

The output should look something like this:

```
121    10
 39    20
 12    30
  7    40
  1   100
```

How to achieve this with the usual set of unix command line tools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quick answer:

```
cat <file> | egrep -o [0-9]+ | sed "s/$/ \/10*10/" | bc | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Detailed answer:

- grep the pattern of your timing or number. You may need to do multiple grep steps to extract exactly the numbers you want from your logs.
- use sed to add arithmetic expression for integer division by desired factor and multiply it back on
- bc performs the calculation
- the well-known sort | uniq combo to count occurrences